# How to evaluate seemingly simple sum to infinity?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sum I am tying to evaluate is the following:

$$\sum\limits_{r=0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{3^r+4^r}{5^r}}$$

This sum seems to tend towards $0$ as the numerator is increasing slower than the denominator, yet I am not seeing a pattern between the terms to exploit.

All attempts to find a common ratio between terms were futile.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: This is a sum of two geometric series.

Comment: You are right! I cannot believe I missed such an elegant solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{3^r+4^r}{5^r}=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^r+\sum_{r=0}^\infty\left(\frac45\right)^r=\frac{1}{1-\frac35}+\frac{1}{1-\frac45}=\frac{15}{2}
\end{align*}